# How & works when int res=num1 & num2 where num1 and num2 are integer type

Tags: c#-4.0

How `&` works when

```
int num1=10,num2=9;
int res=num1 & num2; // where num1 and num2 are integers
```

the value of `res=8;` How it is working

Comment: Plug: I wrote a blog post on the matter a while ago: [Using “or” to combine A and B? Explaining that bitmask thing](http://bit.ly/jRFpqe) (Yes, it discusses bitwise AND as well)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `&` is a bitwise-AND operator. Each bit in the result is set only if the corresponding bit is also set in both num1 *and* num2.

It may make more sense if you write the numbers in binary:

```
num1           1010 = 10
num2           1001 =  9
------------------------
num1 & num2    1000 =  8
```